# Excel 2013 - Data Validation - Create a drop down list with values if a second criteria is matched

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm gonna simplify my problem as much as possible. I got two sheets in Excel. In the first sheet I'm creating a list of locations. I need to choose an area where the location is situated in column A before I can type in the location in column B. In the next column (C) there's gonna be an ID which is automatically created (for the first location ID-001, the second gets the ID 002, etc.).

In my second sheet I'm creating a list of assets. Therefore, again, I choose an area in column A and type in the name of the asset in column B.
Now I want to have a drop down list in column C where it shows me only those IDs from the first table where the area is the same.
I've tried to use the OFFSET function but the point which is missing is some kind of "select if" (like countif or sumif) to limit the list of IDs to those having the same area.

There can be many locations and assets in each area, but every location and every asset can only be mapped to one location.

Looking forward to your answers guys! Either an excel solution or a vba solution would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create a helper column that include unique values to use in VLOOKUP. For example; let's say you have Area1, Area2, Area3 and Area1 (again) and goes on. Merge this values with incremental values (e.g. 01, 02, 03, ...) and create 01Area1, 01Area2, 01Area3 and *02Area1*.
Now you know what to call for each list item in second sheet. 
If you select *Area1* in A column, then you need search *incremental number* & *Area1*.
Incremental numbers by values can be created by *COUNTIF* function that uses expanding range:

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)
```

By expanding range, the formula counts only the values up to its own row.
Only handicap of this method you need create list items in *elsewhere*

Here two links that describes similar use.:

1. https://www.spreadsheetweb.com/how-to-get-nth-match-with-vlookup/
2. https://www.spreadsheetweb.com/pricing-list-quoting-tool-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is acceptable to have the Locations table sorted, the simplest solution entails just a relatively short data validation formula and a couple of named ranges. No helper columns or rows are required.

Set up two example worksheets, `Locations` and `Assets`, like this:

[image: Screenshot of Locations worksheet]  [image: Screenshot of Assets worksheet]

Add two Defined Names:

1. `Areas` → `=Locations!$A:$A`
2. `IDs` → `=Locations!$C:$C`

Finally add an In-cell dropdown List data validation to `C2` in the `Assets` worksheet with the following formula, and then fill/copy-paste the cell downwards:

```dart
=INDEX(IDs,MATCH(A2,Areas,0)):INDEX(IDs,MATCH(A2,Areas,0)+COUNTIF(Areas,A2)-1)
```

The drawbacks of this method are:

- Defined names need to be used
- The Locations table must be sorted
- Other tables in the the Locations sheet cannot safely intersect the `Area` column unless they are guaranteed not to contain values matching the Location table's `Area` values.

---

The following alternative solution overcomes the drawbacks except the other-tables one. It does, however, use cells in the Assets worksheet to store the items of the dropdown lists.

The Assets worksheet is set up with additional columns:

[image: Screenshot of Assets worksheet]

This time, the `C2` data validation formula is:

```dart
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNA(C2:INDEX(2:2,COLUMN(C2)-1+COUNTA(C2:INDEX(2:2,COLUMNS(2:2))))))=0,$I$1,C2:INDEX(2:2,COLUMN(C2)-1+COUNTA(C2:INDEX(2:2,COLUMNS(2:2)))-SUMPRODUCT(--ISNA(C2:INDEX(2:2,COLUMN(C2)-1+COUNTA(C2:INDEX(2:2,COLUMNS(2:2))))))))
```

Enter this formula in `D2` and fill down:

```dart
=
IF(
  SUMPRODUCT(
    --ISNA(
      E2:INDEX(
        (2:2),
        COLUMN(E2)-1+MAX(1,COUNTA(E2:INDEX(2:2,COLUMNS(2:2))))
      )
    )
  )=0,
  "ERROR",
  "ok"
)
```

Multi-cell array-enter this last formula into the cells starting from `E2` and going as far right as the maximum number of expected Locations in an Area (for the example shown I have used `E2:I2`):

```dart
=
INDEX(
  Locations!$C:$C,
  IFERROR(
    SMALL(
      IFERROR(1/(1/(
        (Locations!$A$2:INDEX(Locations!$A:$A,COUNTA(Locations!$A:$A))=IF($A2="",NA(),$A2))
        *ROW($A$2:INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA(Locations!$A:$A)))
      )),FALSE ),
      COLUMN(INDEX(2:2,1):INDEX(2:2,MAX(2,COUNTIF(Locations!$A$2:INDEX(Locations!$A:$A,COUNTA(Locations!$A:$A)),$A2))))
    ),
    NA()
  )
)
```

Comment: Notes and explanation to come after I get some sleep ;-)

Comment: First of all, thank you very much robinCTS for your awesome work! I actually have had the same idea with the index match, but the problem is, that the list cannot be sorted since it won't be me filling out the lists but a lot of other people.
Also the alternative including the helper columns is difficult to implement since there will be really lots of locations.
Btw: I'm getting this error using your first index match formula: "You may not use reference operators (such as unions, intersections, and ranges) or array constants for Data Validation criteria.
Any idea why it's working with you?

Comment: @Moritz It should be very easy to add an event handler in VBA to automatically sort the list as soon as you switch away from the Locations sheet. If this is acceptable I will add the code to my answer. Yeah, I figured the helper columns might be a problem. That's why I added the sorting solution. As for that error, it *seems* to be complaining about the `:`, but that doesn't make any sense. Data validation *does* tend to spit out that error for *a lot* of reasons ;-). I'm using Excel 2007, and data validation *has* changed in the next versions, but it shouldn't have affected that formula.  …

Comment: … What version are you using? Also, did you create a new workbook and set it up exactly like my example? In that new workbook, for the data validation formula try `=A2:A8` (*just* in case ;-) ), and then try copying the Locations table to the Assets sheet and changing the defined names to point to the two columns there. Finally, after that last test, try changing the defined names in the formula to use the columns directly. If you have Excel 2010+, also try using the columns in the Locations sheet directly. This is really puzzling.